# como evitar la duplicidad de datos

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que antes de ejecutar la inserción de datos a sql que me consulte si hay datos iguales en este caso tengo un campo llamado cédula que es el que pienso utilizar para la comprobación pero no se como realizar la consulta. AYUDA POR FAVOR

Answer (score 1):

simplemente en el campo ponle el atributo unique (UQ), en la base de datos, y ya no te dejará poner un registro igual.  Desde el front debes hacer una consulta de el usuario que el numero de documento se parezca al que envian, es una consulta mas o menos asi, "Select user from tabla where id like %iddelfront%"; entonces si esa consulta retorna algo es porque hay un registro, si retorna algo no guardará nada, esa validación la puedes hacer en el controlador que de guardado que tienes, eso si quieres que le aparezca un mensaje de error al usuario en el frontend, porque solo con poner el atributo en el campo ya tendrías.  Espero te sirva.

Comment: buenas, primero gracias por tomarte el tiempo de comentar. (soy novato), el atributo unique es en formulario o te refieres a llave primaria en sql por que si es llave primaria se usarla pero el usuario aun podra enviar datos iguales solo que el sistema explotara

Comment: puedes poner cualquier campo unique así no sea llave primaria, solo crea el campo asi identification varchar(45) not null unique; y listo o en la interfaz gráfica del sql marca la casilla UQ.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (ID,LastName)
);

Comment: en cuanto a la validación haz lo que haces cuando listas algo, veo que usas las consultas nativas en el código, haz lo mismo, y pones una condición que si esa consulta retorna datos, no deje guardar ya tu controlarías que mensaje saldría.  Así como veo que lo estas haciendo.  Saludos.

Comment: ok todo bien hermano, gracias me ayudo

Comment: gracias hermano, me ayudo

Comment: me da error bastianburst no me lee el mensaje que le digo que haga cuando la consulta sea igual a mi textbox aun me da error: if (consulta==txtcedula.Text)
                                        {
                                            MessageBox.Show("No se puede agregar este cliente, por que ya existe uno con esta cedula.");
                                        }

Comment: muestra el codigo, la consulta es select persona from tabla where identification = txtcedula...; debes pasar el valor para que lo pase a la consulta; si esa consulta retorna algo no deja crear, si esa consulta es vacía o empty entonces deja crear, la verdad importa poco lo que devuelva, lo que  te interesa realmente es que retorne o no algo.  en realidad eso no se va a validar en el formulario si no después de pinchar el botón de guardar.

Answer (score 0):

También como te decian puedes controlar la forma en la que se guardan los datos siempre preguntando si ya existe en la BD ejemplo:

```
        var duplicado = db.Trabajador.Any(a => a.TrabajadorId == ObjetoParametro.TrabajadorId);

        if (duplicado)
         {            
            ModelState.AddModelError("TrabajadorId", "Ya existe este trabajador");
         }
          else
           {
                //Creas el trabajador
                db.SaveChanges();                   
           }
```